# row.names disappear when subsetting

Tags: r, subset

I have a problem subsetting my data. I don't include other an example because when I do it the same problem doesn't arise!

I show you what is happening with an example. 
1. When I subset more than one row from my dataset in the output I get the row.names.
2. However, when I only subset one row I don't get the row.name.

```
> site.scr[1:2, ]
           PC1         PC2
756 -0.2232937  0.04370646
45  -0.0714013 -0.45858786

> site.scr[1:1, ]
        PC1         PC2 
-0.22329371  0.04370646
```

Do you know why this may be happening? I don't have a clue! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
site.scr[1:1, , drop=FALSE]
```

R drops the second dimension (converts `site.scr` from `matrix` to `vector`) if there is only one dimension in the output.

Comment: I think this should be `site.scr[1:1, , drop=FALSE]`